# Evaluating integrals in the paper Auto-Encoding Variational Bayes

Tags: probability, integration

This is the first time that I'm asking on this site so apologies in advance if it's not quite the usual standard.

I'm going thorough the paper Auto-Encoding Variational Bayes https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.6114 and in page 10 appendix B there is a simple enough looking equation that I don't fully understand how they got the results they have.

$$\int q_{\phi}(\mathbf{z})log\,p(\mathbf{z})d\mathbf{z} = ... $$

when I expand $log\,p(\mathbf{z})$ I get 
$$log\,p(\mathbf{z}) = log\, \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{z}; \mathbf{0}, \mathbf{I}) = 
 log\, det(2\pi I)^{-1/2}\,e^{-1/2 \,\mathbf{z}'I\mathbf{z}} = \frac{-J}{2}\, log \,2\pi \, -\frac{1}{2}\left\lVert \mathbf{z} \right\rVert ^{2}$$
where $J$ is the dimension of $\mathbf{z}$. From there it is easy to see that the term $\int q_{\phi}(\mathbf{z})\frac{-J}{2}\, log \,2\pi\, d\mathbf{z}$ evaluates to $\frac{-J}{2}\, log \,2\pi$ given that the integral over a density function evaluates to 1 which is in agreement with the paper. However I'm not sure how to proceed with the second part $\int q_{\phi}(\mathbf{z})\frac{-J}{2}\, \left\lVert \mathbf{z} \right\rVert ^{2} d\mathbf{z}$.

I'll really appreciate if anyone that knows could please explain what is it that I'm misunderstanding.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually not terribly difficult, the key observation is that the integral actually splits into a bunch of single variable integrals,

\begin{align}
\int q_\phi({\bf z})\|{\bf z}\|_2^2d{\bf z}&=\int q_\phi({\bf z})(z_1^2+\ldots+z_n^2)d{\bf z}\notag\\
&=\int q_\phi({\bf z})z_1^2d{\bf z} + \ldots + \int q_\phi({\bf z})z_n^2d{\bf z}\notag\\
&=\int q_\phi(z_1)z_1^2dz_1 + \ldots + \int q_\phi(z_n)z_n^2dz_n\notag.
\end{align}

Now since $q_\phi(z_i) = N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, the above expression can be rewritten in expected value form as,

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\text{E}Z_i^2,$$

and using the identity that $\text{Var}X = \text{E}X^2 - (\text{E}X)^2$, we obtain,

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\text{E}Z_i^2=\sum_{i=1}^n(\text{E}Z_i)^2 + \text{Var}Z_i=\sum_{i=1}^n\mu_i^2 + \sigma_i^2.$$

Comment: Thanks for your kind help it is really helpful. I've actually started going down that path but missed the last step of interpreting as an expectation.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a bit late, but may be useful for someone needing the full derivation of KL divergence:

### Worked derivation of KL-divergence

By definition of KL divergence:
$$
\begin {equation}
D_{KL}(Q||P) = \int Q(X) \log \frac{Q(X)}{P(X)}dX
\end {equation}
$$

Or, put another way:
$$
\begin {equation}
\int Q(X) \bigg[\log P(X) - \log Q(X) \bigg]dX = \int Q(X)\log P(X)dX - \int Q(X) \log Q(X)dX
\end {equation}
$$

First, let's expand $\log Q(X)$:
$$ \log Q(X) = \log \bigg[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}}\bigg] $$
Then using the rule $\log(XY) = \log(X) + \log(Y)$

$$
\log Q(X) = \log \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} - \frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}
$$

#### So we can compute the 1st term in eq. (2) $\int Q(X)\log Q(X)$:

$$
\int Q(X)\log Q(X) = \int Q(X) \bigg[\log\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} - \frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2} \bigg] dX
$$

Expand the brackets:
$$
\int Q(X)\log Q(X) = \int Q(X) \log\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} dX - \int Q(X) \frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2} dX
$$

In the first term we take out of the integral the $\log\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}$ because it doesn't depend on X, what's left is equal to 1 (by the definition of normal distribution). Because $\log\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} = \log(1)-\log \sqrt{2\pi} + \log\sqrt{\sigma^2} = -\frac{1}{2}\log 2\pi - \frac{1}{2}\log \sigma^2$, and by definition $Var(X) = \int Q(X) (x-\mu)^2 dX = \sigma^2 $, we can write:

$$
-\frac{1}{2}\log 2\pi -\frac{1}{2}\log\sigma^2 - \frac{1}{2 \sigma^2}\sigma^2 = 
-\frac{1}{2}\log 2\pi -\frac{1}{2} + \log\sigma^2
$$
Because we have are going to have a batches of $\mu$ and $\sigma$, we need to sum over the batch length $J$:

$$\boxed{-\frac{1}{2}\log 2\pi -\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^{J} \bigg[1 + \log\sigma_j^2 \bigg]}$$

#### Now let's do the second term in eq. (2) $\int Q(X)\log P(X)dX$

First, let's take the log apart:
$$ \log P(X) = \log \bigg[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}}\bigg] $$

Since $P(X) \stackrel{}{\sim} \mathcal{N} (0, I) $ is a normal distribution with $\mu = 0$ and $\sigma = 1$, we can write:

$$ \log P(X) = \log \bigg[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\bigg] = 
-\frac{1}{2}\log 2\pi -\frac{x^2}{2}||x||^2
$$

$$\int Q(X) \bigg[ -\frac{1}{2}\log 2\pi -\frac{x^2}{2}||x||^2 \bigg]dX$$

$$-\frac{1}{2} \log 2\pi \int Q(X) dX - \frac{1}{2}\int Q(X) ||x||^2 dX
$$

Since by definition (see Wikipedia) $Var(X) = E[X^2] - E[X]^2 = E[X^2] - \mu^2$ and $\int Q(X) ||x||^2 dX$ is the expectation of  $||X||^2$, i.e. $\int Q(X) ||x||^2 = E[X^2] = Var(X) + E[X]^2 = \sigma^2 + \mu^2 $, we can write:

$$
-\frac{1}{2}\log 2\pi - \frac{1}{2} E[X^2] = -\frac{1}{2}\log 2\pi - \frac{1}{2} E[\mu^2+\sigma^2]
$$

Since $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are vectors, we need to replace the expectation with a sum:

$$
-\frac{1}{2}\log 2\pi - \frac{1}{2} E[X^2] =$$

$$
\boxed {-\frac{1}{2}\log 2\pi - \frac{1}{2} \sum_{j=1}^{J}[\mu_j^2+\sigma_j^2]}
$$

#### Finally we can put the 1st and 2nd terms together to get $D_{KL}$

$$
D_{KL} = -\frac{1}{2}\log 2\pi -\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^{J} \big(1 + \log\sigma_j^2 \big) - \Bigg(-\frac{1}{2}\log 2\pi - \frac{1}{2} \sum_{j=1}^{J}\big(\mu_j^2+\sigma_j^2\big) \Bigg)
$$

$$
\boxed {D_{KL} = -\frac{1}{2}
\sum_{j=1}^{J} \big(1 + \log\sigma_j^2 - \mu_j^2 - \sigma_j^2 \big)}
$$

Comment: I've just worked through your derivation. I have a few questions/comments. I think there's a typo in your 7th main equation (immediately after variance definition): RHS should be $-\frac{1}{2}\log{2\pi}-\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\log\sigma^2\right)$. Where did $||x||^2$ in equation 10 come from? Shouldn't this whole derivation always refer to the random variable $X$ and never a sample $x$? You have $-\frac{1}{2}\log{2\pi}$ where the paper has $-\frac{J}{2}\log{2\pi}$. I recognise that they get cancelled out regardless, but which is correct? And, is J over samples or dimensions of z?